# i have installed curl in Linux but not working

Tags: php, curl

I have install **curl** in Linux `curl -V` is working i have added `extension = curl.so` and restarted my apache2 service  but still in `php_info();` in don't seem to be enabled and also `var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));` return me false that mean extension is not enabled

Comment: "I have install curl" — How?

Comment: "in Linux" — Which Linux? There are lots of distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install php5 extension too :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

You will need to restart the server afterwards:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Alternatively, if you are using php-fpm, you'll need to restart php5-fpm instead

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: i have installed curl when i run this comment curl -V it return my curl version. php 5 extension must be installed as well ?

Comment: is there any different between curl and php5 extension for curl ?

Comment: you've installed curl distribution for unix, it allow you to use curl via command line but , if you want to use curl functions of php you need to install php5-curl extension

Answer (score 0):

To download curl with f.ex. Ubuntu and Apache server:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If you are using something like XAMPP uncomment line:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

in `xampp\apache\bin\php.ini` or `xampp\php\php.ini`

And restart your Apache service.